# Getting 16.04 to recognize mpeg-2 liles from windows NTFS usb HDD

Tags: video, files

I have copied video files from a Humax PVR recorder onto a windows 7 formatted USB HDD, the files play OK on a windows computer but Ubuntu 16.04 on a different computer does not recognize the files and I have tried a couple of file management software from Ubuntu soft centre with no luck.

The widows computer lists the files as  HJM file, HJTSM file, NTS file and the important one MPEG-2 TS Video